# .NET web service for printing HTML docs to a network printer

Tags: .net, web-services, printing

I need to build a web service that can receive an HTML document and send it to the printer. That service must receive the HTML as input, and then send it to a printer on the network. I have read a lot about PrintDocument, but it doesn't appear to be a viable solution for sending something like a pre-formatted document (HTML in this case) or file to the printer. Instead, it expects your code to orchestrate both the content and layout of each page, using individuals commands to print lines of text, graphics, etc. In my case, the HTML itself should define the page layout. I just need to blindly print the HTML doc in the same way a desktop browser would, but programmatically as a service, without any user input.

Context: we have iOS devices (iPad, iPod, etc.) that need to print HTML pages, but we cannot use AirPrint technology for a variety of reasons. First of all, AirPrint requires the iOS device to be on the same network segment as the printer, which won't be the case. We must be able to use any printer on the corporate network. Second, the printers we are using are not AirPrint compatible.

Proposed Solution: Build a web service (either REST or SOAP) in .NET that will run on a Windows Server where the network printer has been configured, and the driver has been installed. Have the iOS app send the HTML document to the web service. The web service will somehow send the HTML it receives to the remote network printer that is configured locally on the Windows Server where the web service is hosted...

Any ideas on how to print an in-memory HTML doc, similar to the way a browser would, but from a web service, without any UI?

Comment: **What have you tried so far and what the difficulties you're facing?** Create a WCF service accepting encoded HTML string sounds like a simple task to accomplish, doesn't it?

Comment: Agreed. Building a WCF service to receive the encoded HTML is straight-forward. Challenge for me is sending that HTML to the printer as a document. The PrintDocument object ironically does not support printing an existing in-memory document. It has you send a series of commands to the printer, dictating the page layout in code. So I'm wondering what is the best way to programmatically print a pre-formed doc. Some people have used a shell command, but they had to grant admin rights to the WCF service and indirectly open another app, instead of printing in-process like PrintDocument does.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like [PhantomJS](http://phantomjs.org/) could work for your need. It would allow you to turn an HTML file into a PDF (among other formats), which you could then send to a printer.

You'll probably want to look at the "[rasterize](https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/blob/master/examples/rasterize.js)" example for your situation.